# Как написать консольную программу, которая выведет в консоль букву “V”?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задание: Напишите консольную программу, которая выведет в консоль букву “V”, высота которой вводится с клавиатуры. Пример вывода для высоты 5 представлен ниже:
[image: Пример]

Самый удачный вариант кода:

```
h = int(input('Введите высоту фигуры: '))
y = h // 2

for i in range(0, h):
    print(' ' * i + 'V', ' ' * (y - i + 3 + h % 2),  ' ' * (y - i + 3 + h % 2) + 'V')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто добавьте в конце ещё вывод пробелов и одного символа, так-то у вас почти все вроде сделано

Comment: range(0, h-1) и последний принт вне цикла с одной “v”.

Comment: `print(' ' * i + 'V', ' ' * (2*(h-i)-4),  'V' if i<h-1 else '')`

Comment: Интересные у вас задания )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SP = " "
V = "V"

h = int(input('Введите высоту фигуры: '))

pairs = [(i, 2 * (h - i) - 3) for i in range(h)]

first_parts = [i*SP + V + j*SP for i, j in pairs]
last_chars = (h-1)*[V] + [""]

for i in range(h):
    print(first_parts[i] + last_chars[i])
```

---

*Объяснение:*

- `pairs` - это список пар `(пробелов_перед_V, пробелов_после_V)`

  Количество символов в левой половине от вертикальней оси симметрии это константа равна `h-1`, т.к. самое последнее `V` — прямо на оси симметрии — находится на позиции `h`.

  ```
  V···|       <---- i=0 ---->       V···        
  ·V··|       <---- i=1 ---->       ·V··        
  ··V.|       <---- i=2 ---->       ··V.        
  ···V|       <---- i=3 ---->       ···V        
  ····V       <---- i=4 ---->       ····
  12345              ↑              1234      
  <-h->              |            
   h=5       for i in range(h)    (h-1)=4
  ```

  Это константное количество `(h-1)` символов заключает в себе

  - пробелы *перед* буквой **V**  (`i` позиций),
  - *самую* букву **V**  (`1` позиция),
  - пробелы *после* буквы `V` - значит, их будет `(h-1) - (i+1)`.

  Всех пробелов между обеими буквами `V` будет в два раза больше, плюс один пробел прямо в оси симметрии, т. е.

  ```
  2·[(h-1) – (i+1)] + 1  =  2·(h – i – 2) + 1  =  2·(h – i) – 4 + 1  =  2·(h – i) – 3
  ```

  потому пары в генераторе списка именно такие (`(i, 2 * (h - i) - 3)`).
- список `last_chars` например такой:

  ```
  ["V", "V", "V", "V", "V", ""]
  ```

  т.е. последний элемент – пустая строка.

Answer (score 1):

Мой способ:

```py
h = int(input('Введите высоту фигуры: '))
s=[]

for i in range(h):
    s.append(' '*i+"V"+' '*(h+2-i-2))

for l, r_ in zip(s, s[:-1:][::-1]):
    if len(r_)>2:
        print(l, r_)
print(' '*h+'V')
```

Answer (score 0):

В приведенной Вами попытке решения есть две проблемы:

1. Последнюю строку нужно рисовать не в цикле, чтобы на не было не два символа 'V'
2. Количество отступов между символами.

Привожу своё решение этой задачи.
Здесь последний символ рисуется вне цикла отдельным вызовом `print`

```
h = int(input('Введите высоту фигуры: '))
for i in range(h-1):
    print(' ' * i + 'V' + ' ' * (2* h - 3 - 2 * i) + 'V')
print(' ' * (h-1) + 'V')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё вариант, для общего развития:

```
import numpy as np

h = 8
sym="V"

print('\n'.join(''.join(sym if x else " " for x in y ) for y in np.delete
                (np.concatenate([np.eye(h, dtype=int),
                                 np.rot90(np.eye(h, dtype=int))], axis=1), h,1)))
```

```
V             V
 V           V 
  V         V  
   V       V   
    V     V    
     V   V     
      V V      
       V       ​
```